# c# check if task is running

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to be able to check if a specific task is running:

```
            Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    int counter = 720;
                    int sleepTime = 7000;
                    int operationId = 0;
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "GetTasksStatusAsync";
......
```

so in my code somewhere in another class I need to check "GetTasksStatusAsync" is running.
thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => ...);

if(t.Status.Equals(TaskStatus.Running))
{
    //task is running
}
```

Basically I would store my tasks somewhere and make them accessible for other classes. Then you can check the status of the task with the code above. Refer to the [TaskStatus-Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus.aspx).

Comment: I think this is more complete: `if (t.IsCompleted == false && t.Status != TaskStatus.Running &&                t.Status != TaskStatus.WaitingToRun && t.Status != TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation)` this prevents re-start(read start again) starting again inside the if block.

Comment: I had to use an uppercase 'E' in equals, but this worked for me: `t.Status.Equals(TaskStatus.Running)
`

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me.

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => ...);

if(t.IsCompleted.Equals(false))  // or if(t.Status.Equals(TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation)
{
}
```